# email inbox report not properly generating

Tags: java

I have written a java code to generate report from gmail inbox[Primary], but at the time of execution of java code. it is generating all received mail[Primary,Social] and sent mail also. I already included Javax.mail.jar and activation.jar into classpath. 
Please help me to generate report of gmail inbox[Primary] only.
My code is following :-

```
 import java.util.Properties;
    import javax.mail.Authenticator;
    import javax.mail.Folder;
    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.MessagingException;
    import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
    import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Store;

    public class CheckingMails2 {

       public static void check(String host, String storeType, String user,
          String password) 
       {
          try {

          // create properties field
          Properties properties = new Properties();

          properties.put("mail.pop3s.host", host);
          properties.put("mail.pop3s.port", "995");
          properties.put("mail.pop3s.starttls.enable", "true");

          // Setup authentication, get session
          Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties,
             new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                   return new PasswordAuthentication(
                      "sumit.nalui@gmail.com", "********");
                }
             });
          // emailSession.setDebug(true);

          // create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
          Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

          store.connect();

          // create the folder object and open it
          Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("inbox");
          emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

          // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
          Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
          System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

          for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
             Message message = messages[i];
             System.out.println("---------------------------------");
             System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
             System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
             System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
             System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());
             System.out.println("SentDate: " + message.getSentDate().toString());
          }

             //String sentDate = message.getSentDate().toString();

          // close the store and folder objects
          emailFolder.close(false);
          store.close();

          } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (MessagingException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {

          String host = "pop.gmail.com";// change accordingly
          String mailStoreType = "pop3";
          String username = "sumit.nalui@gmail.com";// change accordingly
          String password = "********";// change accordingly

          check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);

       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose you a different approach. Just take a look at **Google REST API**, there you will find calls that can be used to query your email account.

Its pretty straight forward actually

You can query the messages by using labels. Labels are of two types System labels and User Labels.

**You can use the Try It! feature with Google to test it out**

Get labels:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list

For a given label, say CATEGORY_PRIMARY in your case query the messages 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

You can also get the STARRED, CATEGORY_PERSONAL for starred and important emails from the inbox.

Comment: Please help me to write the full code to generate accurate report.

Comment: This SO we don't work for you. We just help you out if you have a problem. Give it a try and then post your code asking for help